# Laravel PSR-0 - concrete class (that extends a abstract class) not loading

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following entry in my `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    ...
    "psr-0": {
        "Latheesan": "app/"
    }
    ...
},
```

And my folder structure looks like this:

[image]

This is my **AbstractReporting** class:

```
<?php namespace Latheesan\Reporting;

abstract class AbstractReporting
{
    // Force Extending class to define these methods
    abstract protected function getReportingData();

    // Common method to transform reporting data to CSV format
    public function toCSV()
    {
        // CSV headers
        $headers = [
            'Content-type'        => 'application/csv'
            , 'Cache-Control'       => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
            , 'Content-type'        => 'text/csv'
            , 'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename='. __CLASS__ .'.csv'
            , 'Expires'             => '0'
            , 'Pragma'              => 'public'
        ];

        // Load reporting data
        $reporting_data = $this->getReportingData();

        // Dynamically write csv
        $callback = function() use ($reporting_data) {
            $h = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            foreach ($reporting_data as $row)
                fputcsv($h, $row);
            fclose($h);
        };

        // Return csv data
        return Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
    }

    // Common method to transform reporting data to PDF format
    // TODO

    // Common method to transform reporting data to JSON format
    // TODO
}
```

and this is my **PackagingLevelsReport** class:

```
<?php namespace Latheesan\Reporting;

class PackagingLevelsReport extends AbstractReporting {

    // Class properties
    protected $reporting_data = [];

    // Class constructor
    public function __construct($date_range) {
        if ($date_range == 'today') {
            $this->reporting_data = [
                'sku' => 'box1',
                'qty' => 10142
            ];
        }
    }

    // Method for returning reporting data
    protected function getReportingData()
    {
        return $this->reporting_data;
    }

}
```

to test this, I created the following entry in my `routes.php`

```
use Latheesan\Reporting;
Route::get('/test', function() {
    return App::make('PackagingLevelsReport')->toCSV();
});
```

When I visit my local dev site url (i.e. http://my-project.local/test) I get the following error:

### Class PackagingLevelsReport does not exist

I have already ran `composer dump-auto` and yet my class is still not being picked up. Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
App::make('PackagingLevelsReport')
```

Try:

```
App::make('Latheesan\Reporting\PackagingLevelsReport')
```

In your version, `App::make` is looking for the class `PackagingLevelsReport` in the global namespace, which isn't where it is located.

**Update**

In response to your follow-up, one solution is to create a [`ServiceProvider`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc#service-providers) that will be able to provide the parameters to the constructor:

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class FooServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $foo = 'foo';
        $this->app->bind('foo', function() use($foo)
        {
            return new Foo($foo);
        });
    }

}
```

Alternatively, if you want to be able to specify the parameter from within the context from which the `App::make` call is being made, just provide a second array parameter:

```
App::make('Latheesan\Reporting\PackagingLevelsReport', ['param1', 'param2'])
```

I think that the second option is what you're looking for.

Comment: Now this appears to be working, however I get a different error now `Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $date_range ]] in class Latheesan\Reporting\PackagingLevelsReport` how do you use `App::make` and specify value for the constructor?

Comment: No prob, glad to help